# Dual and Primal in Linear programming.

Tags: linear-programming

I am stuck on these two questions.

I have tried to get information on these but what am getting is not even close to the questions.

What can you say about the dual if you already know that :

1. an optimal solution to the primal exists with x1 = 0?
2. an optimal solution to the primal exists with x1 > 0?

Comment: What would x1 be?